# Does the size of data to be encrypted influence the security of Gmac?

Tags: gcm

In this link: [Has GMAC mode a future outside GCM?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8749/has-gmac-mode-a-future-outside-gcm), the last comment given by the user Demi, indicates that the larger the size of the text to be encrypted, the lower the security of the gmac.

Why is this happening?